# Access multiple machines externally via RDP

Tags: rdp

I currently port forward port 3389 on my router to the internal IP address of the machine I want to RDP to the most.

I really want to be able to RDP from external to many internal machines.

Can anyone suggest a list / range of ports I could use?

Thanks Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's 2 ways to do this easily

- the first is to set up a [terminal services gateway](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731264(WS.10).aspx) server - this will act as a proxy to the internal machines and let you connect to them via the gateway (recent versions of SBS have this as standard)
- the second is to setup multiple external ports (can be anything) forwarding to the different machines on 3389. This should be possible but will depend on your firewall, for example:

  if 123.123.123.123 is your external ip, and 192.168.0.0/24 is your internal range,

  > forward 123.123.123.123 port 3389 ->
  >   192.168.0.1 port 3389
  >
  > forward 123.123.123.123 port 3390 ->
  >   192.168.0.2 port 3389
  >
  > forward 123.123.123.123 port 3391 ->
  >   192.168.0.3 port 3389

  then connect to each one through the normal rdp client as:

  > 123.123.123.123:3389
  >
  > 123.123.123.123:3390
  >
  > 123.123.123.123:3391

Comment: Hey, thanks for your responce! I think TS Gateway sounds the way to go!